# Is there a way to pass arguments via pipe on bash?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Is there any way to pass arguments via pipe on bash?

something like:

```
echo value1 value2 | mkdir -p ./$1/$2
```

The line above would create the directories ./value1/value2

If this is not possible I would accept suggestions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works in Ubuntu:

```
echo -e value1\\nvalue2|echo mkdir -p ./`line`/`line`
```

I can't guarantee that all `bash` implementations will read the lines in left-to-right order.

Alternatively:

```
echo value1 value2|( read p1 p2; echo mkdir -p ./$p1/$p2 )
```

This will work with all `bash` implementations, but it will need elaboration if either value contains any blanks.

(I have used `echo mkdir` to show the effect.)

Comment: The second alternative is perfect for what I'm doing, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
echo v1 v2 | awk '{print "./"$1"/"$2}' | xargs mkdir -p
```